# How to represent a movement in a feature vector?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction

Which features extraction algo are best suited to extract features from movement of a hand. For example closing my fist, waving hand. Which feature vector or motion vector can be used to represent the gestures? I have read a few research papers but most of them are on static hand gestures.

Answer (score 2):

Check this paper [Action Recognition by Learning Mid-level Motion Features](http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/VACE/VisionResearchGroup/cvpr08/395.pdf) where motion features are build from the optical flow information of a sequence of pictures.